# Avoid blinking terminator cursor when window is not focused

Tags: linux, terminal, i3-window-manager, terminator

When the [terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) window is not focused, the cursor will still be blinking. Is this by design?!
To me, that's optically distracting and I would like to disable it – but still have it blinking when the window is focused.

I guess I could hack together a solution to change the profile (to a profile where cursor blink is disabled) every time the window gets unfocused, but I was hoping for a more straightforward solution.

I'm using i3 as a window manager, in case that's relevant. `terminator -v` shows version 0.98.

Comment: What terminal? You added a "terminator" tag, there are two different terminals of this same name. Could you please clarify which terminal, and which version thereof you use?

Comment: Please make a comment that you've edited the question, otherwise I don't get notified. I've just accidentally happened to check this post minutes after your update.

Comment: terminator 0.98 is quite old, so I assume the rest of your system is also not a brand new one. What's your GTK version? I assume it's older than 3.18.9. GTK version 3.18.9 received a relevant fix (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677329), most likely fixing the behavior for you. [On a side note, you should upgrade to terminator v1.9x, too, 0.9x is contains hundreds of bugs that have been fixed since.]